# CLS_LOG macro does not work in one class

Tags: objective-c, crashlytics

I'm using the Crashlytics CLS_LOG macro throughout my project. It's working everywhere except in one class, where I get `Implicit declaration of function 'CLS_LOG' is invalid in C99`. If I comment out the calls in that one class then the entire project compiles fine.

I'm including Crashlytics in my prefix.pch like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    // Other imports
    #import "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h"
    // Other imports
#endif
```

I've trying clearing pre-compiled headers, reinstalling the Crashlytics framework, and more - nothing has helped.

Any idea what could be breaking the macro in a single class?

Comment: Did you try to `#import "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h"` directly in your class?

Comment: @MaksimPavlov Thanks, I did. If I do `#import "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h"` I get *'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found*. If I do `#import "Crashlytics.h"` I get   *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CLSNSLog", referenced from: ... not found for architecture x86_64*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I had added this class to the compiled sources for a new target (a widget), but I hadn't added the Crashlytics framework to that target.

I also followed the instructions [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184358/how-to-add-the-project-prefix-file-to-photo-extension-target) to create a prefix.pch for the widget target, added Crashlytics to that, and now everything is compiling as expected.